# Change Registry Key to “Prompt for User name and password login” and back to original

Tags: c#, windows-authentication

Hi I found a partial solution for my wish here:
[Update Registry Key to "Prompt for User name and password login"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32076013/update-registry-key-to-prompt-for-user-name-and-password-login)

```
   [AssemblyInitialize]
public static void AssemblyInitialize(TestContext testContext)
{
    long setPrompt = -1;
    string regEditKey = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\1";

    using (RegistryKey regKeys = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.CurrentUser, RegistryView.Registry64).OpenSubKey(regEditKey, true))
    {
        if (regKeys != null)
        {
            setPrompt = Convert.ToInt64(regKeys.GetValue("1A00"));
            if (setPrompt != 65536)
            {
                regKeys.SetValue("1A00", (object)65536, RegistryValueKind.QWord);
                regKeys.Close();
                regKeys.Flush();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The thing is that I would like the IE(11) browser to ask for the credentials(`prompt for user name and password`) when starting my test(`Startup`), and get back to `Automatic logon with current user name and password` on `Teardown`. I'm not sure how to do that when finishing my test.

Comment: How is the question related to `Selenium`?

Comment: it doesn't. just used to add `Selenium` when asking a question. I have removed it. 10x